# Select Element with Data Attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have following markup

```
<div class="cloneLayoutSelect">
    <div class="col2">
        <select name="ingredients[0][name]" id="ingredient" class="select" data-multi-column="true" data-label="Ingredient">
            <option value="0">Carrot</option>
            <option value="1">Milk</option>
            <option value="2">Yogurt</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col2"><input name="ingredients[0][quantity]" id="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" data-multi-column="true" data-label="Quantity" value="" type="text"></div>
    <div class="col1 text-right"><button class="btn btn-default multi-column-2"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></div>
    <div class="clearfix clear"></div>
</div>
```

On click of `button.multi-column-2` I want to

- Get all elements within the parent div `cloneLayoutSelect` and which has the data attribute of `data-multi-column="true"`
- Get value of `data-label` of individual element from the previous match
- Get `input/select/radio/checkbox` value of individual element from the previous match

I tried the following:

```
var elements = $('*[data-multi-column="true"]');
$.each(elements, function(index, htmlElement) {
    var element = $('<div><div/>').html(htmlElement).contents();
});
```

Although it returns me desired result, i have two problems with this

1. It searches in all html markup, which is not what i want, I want to only search it within its parent element `cloneLayoutSelect`.
2. It removes all html within `<div class="col2">`

Any help or pointers is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0e2zbaq8/1/ - what are you trying to do in the each loop

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0e2zbaq8/2/

Comment: _“It search in all html markup, which is not what i want, I want to only search it within its parent element cloneLayoutSelect”_ – well then prepend that to your selector, or use `find()` on those elements.

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny let me check

Comment: @ArunPJohny jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0e2zbaq8/2  , this is what i needed, thanks, can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use relative lookup for the elements so

```
$('button.multi-column-2').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    //use a relative search
    //we are finding the .cloneLayoutSelect ancestor of the clicked(referred by `this`) and is finding descendant elements with the attribute [data-multi-column="true"]
    var $elements = $this.closest('.cloneLayoutSelect').find('*[data-multi-column="true"]');
    $elements.each(function () {
        //for each element found we can read the data-label and value
        var $el = $(this),
            label = $el.data('label'),
            value = $el.val();
        console.log(label, value)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0e2zbaq8/)